# Trying to loop an array thru each row of an Excel file

Tags: python, arrays, excel, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to loop thru each row of an Excel file with each value in an array.   I want first match to print "array value found", if it doesn't find a match I want to print "array value not found"

If mostly works except I want to break out of loop when match found and it doesn't.

Using `lxrd`

```
for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    for n in name_array:
        row_vlaue = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        if row_vlaue[4] == r in name_array:
            print(n, "found")
            break
        else:
            print(n, "not found")
```

Comment: Firstly you have indentation issues. The code, as you have pasted will not execute as expected because indentation matters for context (specifically under the `if` statement. Secondly, do you really have `For` and `If` capitalized? that matters too. Please adjust your code if it is inaccurate.

Comment: So you are checking only against the values in the 5th cell ?

Comment: Yeah 5th cell is correct

Comment: I fixed indents.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that you are searching the values only on the 5th cell (`row_vlaue[4]`), if that's true, then this should be enough:

```
for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_vlaue = sheet.row_values(row_num)
    if row_vlaue[4] in name_array: # this checks if the 5th cell is in your list of searched values
        print(row_vlaue[4], "found on row", row_num)
        name_array.remove(row_vlaue[4]) # we remove the element we've found
        if not name_array: # nothing else to search for
            print("found them all")
            break
else:
    # this else will be executed only if the break was not called
    # this means that there still something left in in list of searched values
    print(name_array, "not found")
```

Later edit: altered the answer in order to get all the searched values

Comment: This does work for the first match.  It finds the the first match between the array and the Excel file. But   I am trying to figure out how to get the first match in the Excel file  for each item in the array.   Then if it doesn't find the array item in the Excel  file, it goes to the else statement .   IIrobably was not very clear.

Comment: oh, that's a total different story, let me try to adjust my response